# Confusion in Spivak's proof of theorem 2-7 in Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

[image]

In the above proof, Spivak suddenly shifts to $f'(a)$ notation which has confused me about whats really going on. How do we apply chain (2-2) rule which was derived for the derivative and not partial derivative? What are the intermediate steps?

From what I figure $$D(f \circ g)(a^j)=Df(a)\circ Dh(a^j) $$
How does the composition on the right-hand side become a product?

Comment: Note that $f\circ h$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so this is just the ordinary derivative we're talking about.

Comment: Yes. That I understand but then we are applying chain rule on functions which are not $R\rightarrow R$

Comment: $Df(a)$ and $Dh(a^j)$ are linear transformations, and you can compute their composition as a product of matrices.